# Oracle Live SQL - Invalid Statement error

Tags: sql, oracle

Using the following two tables, write a query to return the names and purchase frequency of the top three pairs of products most often bought together. The names of both products should appear in one column.

question code on oracle SQL

```
create table orders (order_id int, customer_id int, product_id int);
insert into orders values (1,1,1);
insert into orders values (1,1,2);
insert into orders values (1,1,3);
insert into orders values (2,2,1);
insert into orders values (2,2,2);
insert into orders values (2,2,4);
insert into orders values (3,1,5);

create table products (id int, name varchar2(200));
insert into products values (1, 'A');
insert into products values (2, 'B');
insert into products values (3, 'C');
insert into products values (4, 'D');
insert into products values (5, 'E');
```

answer code is as below, however I am gettingthe following error - can someone please help?
I am using Oracle Live SQL

```
Invalid statement

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

answer code

```
t1 AS (
SELECT o1.product_id AS prod_1, o2.product_id AS prod_2
FROM orders o1
JOIN orders o2
ON o1.order_id = o2.order_id
AND o1.product_id < o2.product_id ),
-- join products table onto this to get product names, concatenate to get product pairs in one column
t2 AS (
SELECT p1.name || ' ' ||p2.name AS product_pair
FROM t1
JOIN products p1
ON t1.prod_1 = p1.id
JOIN products p2
ON t1.prod_2 = p2.id )
-- grouping by product pair, return top 3 entries sorted by purchase frequency
SELECT *, count(*) AS purchase_freq
FROM t2
GROUP BY product_pair
ORDER BY purchase_freq DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: You need a `WITH` first of all.

Comment: ANSI SQL doesn't allow a single `*` to be combined with anything in the SELECT list. Try `SELECT product_pair, count(*) AS purchase_freq` instead.

Comment: And replace `LIMIT 3` with `FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY`.